# Change where Visual Studio looks for project file?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, vcxproj

Is there a way to change where visual studio looks for project files(.vcxproj)? So I can keep all visual studio related files in separate VS folder and have my project still open and save correctly in visual studio.

Comment: Are you referring to your the default location of projects in the Documents folder or some other mechanism?

Comment: Open that file in notepad++ or similar editor; and make the path changes whatever you desire! That'd work.

Comment: @linuxuser27 So when starting a new visual studio project, the project file sits within the project folder by default. When I open a visual studio project via the visual studio solution file (.sln) my project gets setup and everything works. However, if I try and take that project file and instead of having it sit in the project folder, I want to have it sit inside another directory folder. The problem is when I try and do this and open project via .sln file, my project doesn't setup correctly since visual studio can't find the project file anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I can open up visual studio's solution file (.sln) in notepad and edit the path to the project file there. It's can be done on this line:

```
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "Solution", "Project/Project.vcxproj", "{E3671A4E-1047-4D41-8AF1-EA19EAC2C601}"
```

So right now the .sln file is looking for the project file within 'Project/'. All I have to do is change the path here in relation to the solution file.

Comment: Ah. You can also create an empty solution (New Project -> Other Project Types -> Blank Solution) and add existing projects to it. Once the empty solution is make you can add an existing project to a solution by right clicking on the solution and looking for the Add flyout menu.